# Add posts with timber twig into an include

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

On a single page, I need to add an include, on the bottom of the page, that add 3 projects.

I have a content type called projects I made with ACF.

**single-project.twig**

I have a "single-project.twig" page that display the content of a post (which is also a project). At the bottom of this page, I need to add a block like this:

```
{% block related %}
  {% include 'inc-related.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

**inc-related.twig**

Into "inc-related.twig", I have this:

```
{% for post in related_posts %}
  {% if post.thumbnail %}
    <a href="{{post.link}}" class="l-basicgrid-work work">
      <article>
        <figure>
          <img data-src="{{post.get_thumbnail.src('medium_large')|resize(800, 533)}}" alt="{{post.title}}" class="lazy">
        </figure>
        <figcaption>
          <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
        </figcaption>
      </article>
    </a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**related.php**

I also create a "related.php" page, that integrate the following rendering:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['related_posts'] = Timber::get_posts('post_type=project&posts_per_page=3');
Timber::render('inc-related.twig', $context);
```

**Questions**

I have 2 questions:

- The project are not displaying into the single page. What I have done
  wrong?
- Can I select 3 project except the one who is displayed on the
  single page?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have include twig template but not send data to him. Your `related.php` is not include automatically. You should write `$context['related_posts'] = Timber::get_posts('post_type=project&posts_per_page=3');` in your `single-project.twig`. And do not use `post` name in `inc-related.twig`. May be conflict with current post object.

To `single-project.php` add `$context['related_posts'] = Timber::get_posts('post_type=project&posts_per_page=3');`

Comment: Thank you. It looks more logical now to put it into single-project.php. But now, there is a conflict with the current post object as you were thinking. How should I do to avoid conflict?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

**single-project.php**

I have created a single-project.php page. It contains the following script:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();

$args = array(
    // Get post type project
    'post_type' => 'project',
    // Get 3 posts
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    // Order random
    'orderby' => 'rand',
);

$context['related_posts'] = Timber::get_posts( $args );
Timber::render('single-project.twig', $context);
```

**single-project.twig**

On my single-project.twig, I have the code that get the result of the php page. Actually, that code is included into an "inc-related.twig" page. And it works!

```
{% for post in related_posts %}
                    {% if post.thumbnail %}
                        <a href="{{post.link}}" class="l-basicgrid-work work">
                            <article>
                                <figure>
                                    <img data-src="{{post.get_thumbnail.src('medium_large')|resize(800, 533)}}" alt="{{post.title}}" class="lazy">
                                </figure>
                                <figcaption>
                                    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
                                </figcaption>
                            </article>
                        </a>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
```

But on the same page (single-project.twig), I also have data that display content from Advanced Custom Field.

```
                    {% if post.project_images %}
                        {% for item in post.get_field('project_images') %}  
                            <figure class="{{item.project_media_css}}">
                                <img data-src="{{TimberImage(item.project_media).src}}" alt="{{item.alt_media}}" class="lazy">
                            </figure>  
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
```

The problem now is that the ACF field don't return anything.

How should I modify single-project.php to get content from "related_project" and ACF field?

Answer (score 0):

The ACF context is passed to the single page template via Timber `$context`, using the [`get_posts` function](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber/#get_posts).

**single-project.php**

```php
$context['related_posts'] = Timber::get_posts('post_type=project&posts_per_page=3');
```

Twig sends along the [active context by default](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/include.html), so this template is fine as-is.

```
{% block related %}
  {% include 'inc-related.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, the posts in `$context['related_posts']` can be looped over. However, within the `for` loop, refer to each post by anything other than `post`, such as `rel_post`. This avoids conflict with the [regular `post` object](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/).

```
{% for rel_post in related_posts %}
  {% if rel_post.thumbnail %}
    ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```